# NVARCHAR2 data types in an Oracle database with AL32UTF8 character set

Tags: oracle11g

I have inherited an **Oracle 11g** database that has a number of tables with `NVARCHAR2` columns.

Is the `NVARCHAR2` data type necessary to store Unicode if the database already has the `AL32UTF8` character set, and if not, can these columns be converted to `VARCHAR2`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the database character set is `AL32UTF8`, a `VARCHAR2` column will store Unicode data.  Most likely, the columns should be converted to `VARCHAR2`.

Assuming that the national character set is `AL16UTF16`, which is the default and the only sensible national character set when the database character set already supports Unicode, it is possible that the choice to use `NVARCHAR2` was intentional because there is some benefit to the UTF-16 encoding.  For example, if those columns are storing primarily Japanese or Chinese data, UTF-16 would generally use 2 bytes of storage per character rather than 3 bytes in UTF-8.  There may be other reasons that one would prefer one Unicode encoding to another that might come into play here as well.  Most of the time, though, people creating `NVARCHAR2` columns in a database that supports Unicode are doing so unintentionally, not because they did a thorough analysis of the benefits of different Unicode encodings.

Comment: a very nice, timely, and comprehensive answer. Thanks.